# first wordpress plugin with Fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to get a simple plugin and got error in my first steps..

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:!test
*/
require_once(includes_url() . '/pluggable.php');

function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    return $user->exists();
}
echo is_user_logged_in();
?>
```

Comment: Could you mention the error here?

Comment: Is it all the core of your plugin? If yes, it's incorrect. You need to define plugins meta first, and after add a shortcode, action and so on, depended on your task. For more information, read this [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Comment: @Akshay 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_user_logged_in()

Answer (score 1):

You can't call function directly in your plugin file. Instead of it, call it inside the hook, for ex.:

```
function my_shortcode_func( $atts ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user->exists(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_func' );
```